# Client.py Error: if r.status_code != 200 and self.raise_Exception (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

После запуска кода Python для перевода googletrans я получаю эту ошибку на client.py, в которой говорится:

```
 if r.status_code != 200 and self.raise_Exception:
            raise Exception('Unexpected status code "{}" from {}'.format(
                r.status_code, self.service_urls))
```

Обычно после 10 файлов скрипт внезапно останавливается и выдает мне эту ошибку. Но если я снова запущу только этот файл, он будет работать очень хорошо.

[См. Этот экран для печати:](https://snipboard.io/f6VpuA.jpg)

**ошибка кода**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\traducere-Nicu_v6.py", line 152, in <module>
    selectare_text()
  File "C:\test\traducere-Nicu_v6.py", line 140, in selectare_text
    continut_tradus = continut_tradus + selectare_traducere_continut(continut[1], delimitatori_text_interior_articol) # articol
  File "C:\test\traducere-Nicu_v6.py", line 100, in selectare_traducere_continut
    translated_text = traducere_text(extracted_text)
  File "C:\test\traducere-Nicu_v6.py", line 62, in traducere_text
    translation = translator.translate(txt, dest=destination_language).text
  File "C:\Users\Castel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 194, in translate
    data, response = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "C:\Users\Castel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 122, in _translate
    if r.status_code != 200 and self.raise_Exception:
AttributeError: 'Translator' object has no attribute 'raise_Exception'
```

вы можете найти мой код Python здесь

https://pastebin.com/wf0d7UGz

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибки

Comment: это не текст ошибки, а фрагмент кода

Comment: Я обновил свой пост, я поставил ошибку и весь код

Comment: Я прочитал обновленный вопрос, ваш собственный ответ на этот вопрос, и понял, что вы ничего не понимаете. Ошибка у вас в том, что у объекта отсутствует свойство raise_Exception. В своем ответе вы пишете о том, что проблема якобы связана с подключением к интернету. Ошибка, которая у вас выводится, с интернетом вообще не связана.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну видимо все-таки код ответа != 200, иначе бы до raise_Exception выполнение не дошло. И похоже это бага в пакете googletrans. В версии на гитхабе кстати похоже исправленная версия лежит, а на pypi не обновили: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/blob/d15c94f176463b2ce6199a42a1c517690366977f/googletrans/client.py#L87

Comment: @JustMe попробуйте скачать googletrans с гитхаба: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans (кнопка code -> dowlnoad ZIP), потом из архива установить через `pip install -U py-googletrans-master.zip` (заменить на правильное имя файла), потом добавьте текст ошибки, если она возникнет.

Comment: @insolor Что приходит не 200 это понятно, но ведь все равно надо исправлять не ту часть, которая отвечает за обработку ответа с сервера, а ту, в которой возникает ошибка.

Comment: Я заметил, что все файлы переводятся, но время от времени он прерывается. И мне нужно продолжить с того места, где он остановился. Так что если вы переводите все файлы, значит, ошибка не в коде.

Comment: @JustMe, чтобы не гадать, нужно смотреть что за ошибку все-таки возвращает сервер, для этого нужно обновить пакет googletrans с github. А потом уже от этого принимать какие-то решения.

Comment: Я обновил библиотеки googletrans на github. Но это все равно дает мне ту же ошибку. Кто-нибудь из тех, кто видел мой код Python, знает, как исправить ошибку в моем коде? Я правда не знаю.

Comment: "Но это все равно дает мне ту же ошибку" - не может давать ту же ошибку, может давать ошибку, которая кажется вам похожей. Скопируйте текст ошибки и добавьте в вопрос или в комментарий. "Кто-нибудь из тех, кто видел мой код Python" - вы не привели ни сам код, ни ссылку на него, не знаю кто мог видеть ваш код.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать вот эту библиотеку: https://github.com/Animenosekai/translate, она более стабильно работает. Можно сказать что библиотека вляется форком, т.к. использует примерно тот же алгоритм что и py-googletrans. Или есть возможность используйте мои форк: https://github.com/Animenosekai/translate/pull/15

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что проблема связана с подключением к Интернету / серверами. Если код не подключает какую-то секунду или минуту к googletrans, я получаю эту ошибку. Или если мое соединение пропадет на несколько секунд.

Итак, я считаю, что это проблема с подключением.

проверьте эту ссылку

https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2152

Comment: Зависит от конкретного кода ошибки (который вы не привели в вопросе). Если код ошибки 403, например, то проблема не с подключением к Интернету / серверами, а с самим запросом.

Comment: Я обновил свой пост, я поставил ошибку и весь код